# Connected reduced proper $k$-scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Any connected reduced proper $k$-scheme is irreducible? Here $k$ is a field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can take the union of two projective lines that intersect transversely at a point.  Concretely, this can be given as $\text{Proj} (k[X,Y,Z]/(XY))$, the union of the $X$- and $Y$-axes in the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much.